# Is there a way to set "escapeXml" project wide?

Tags: jsp

I have a Java EE app that is vulnerable to XSS due to user controlled input not being escaped in the JSP files. Example:

```
<input type="text" id="username" value="${user.username }" />
```

I found that I can resolve this by adding a  to the user controlled input and that resolves the issue. So that line becomes:

```
<input type="text" id="username" value="<c:out value="${user.username}"/>" />
```

The issue is that there are cases like this all over the project that would need to be modified. Is there a way to globally escapeXml in these instances instead of having to add c:out tags to every single one?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It's often better to handle that on the back end, e.g., just filter everything that's being exposed to the client side.

Comment: Thanks, for whatever reason even if I escape the contents on the server side, the JSP view seems to decode it before displaying.

For example, if I escape the "<" and ">" characters as their &gt; and &lt; counterparts to stop the XSS, the browser still eventually seems to be receiving them as "<" and ">" and the malicious script will still run.